# How I can do a search with two input text, one for search and other for exclude

Tags: laravel

I have two input text in my frontend, I need that the first input search the word and the second input exclude the word, example: Input 1: Music, Input 2: Jazz, the result must be music except Jazz.

Controller:

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $videos = Video::search($request->buscar)
                    ->paginate(12);
    return view('results', compact('videos'));
}
```

Model:

```
public function scopeSearch($query, $find)
{
    $search = explode(" ", $find);
    $total = count($search);

    $array = array();
    for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++ ) {
         if( $i == 0 ) {
              $array = $query->where(DB::raw("CONCAT(title, ' ', description)"), "LIKE", "%".Stemm_es::stemm($search[$i])."%");
          } else {
              $array = $array->orWhere(DB::raw("CONCAT(title, ' ', description)"), "LIKE", "%".Stemm_es::stemm($search[$i])."%");
          }
    }

    return $array;

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to search in? and you should include the code you have already tried, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Describe better what is logic, when is used one and when second search field. Also post code you made so far.

Comment: Im so sorry, I updated my ask.

Comment: Tpojka when I use the first is a simple search and is working good, when I use both (first and secound) the search must find in the `DB` the word of the first `input` content in my fields, except (excluding) all results have the word of secound `input`